Identify a movie about a little girl who has conversation with a patient
I am sure I saw this movie between 2008 and 2012.
It might have been set in the 1940s or about that era.
I think the protagonist is a stunt double or something like that. He had an accident which rendered him paralyzed for life in bed in a hospital.
What made it worse for him is that the woman he loved (and still loves), had to leave him for another man, after the accident, since she can't spend her life with him like that.
This story is told throughout the movie in installments and is interrupted by a sequence of events in which a little girl asks this patient some personal questions and he remembers something, then we are taken back to his earlier memories.
I remember that little girl having a genuine acting skills. (Either that or she really was sad and crying when the caught it on camera).
I think the accident involves jumping from a train, or a bridge. Not too sure.
At some point, this patient tries to commit suicide by asking the girl to give him a gun, or to shoot him, or to take his life some way or the other.
The spoken language is English, but the location seems to be European (maybe Italy, or Spain). I could be mistaken, but again it could be Portuguese. However all actors speak English (although with an accent).

I guess you mean the Movie The Fall(2006)
It does not match every detail of your description, but some specific points...

At a Los Angeles hospital in the 1920s, Alexandria is a child
  recovering from a broken arm. She befriends Roy Walker, a movie stunt
  man with legs paralyzed after a fall. At her request, Roy tells her an
  elaborate story about six men of widely varied backgrounds who are on
  a quest to kill a corrupt provincial governor. Between chapters of the
  story, Roy inveigles Alexandria to scout the hospital's pharmacy for
  morphine. As Roy's fantastic tale nears its end, Death seems close at
  hand.

Here is the trailer:




That is exactly the movie i was looking for. I guess my memory is failing me a little, but it had enough information to identify it
